# Problems getting data from XML using Nokogiri and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get information from a XML file with Nokogiri. I can retrieve file using

```
f = File.open("/my/path/file.xml")
cac=Nokogiri::XML(f)
```

And what a get is a fancy noko:file. My row tags are defined like

```
<z:row ...info..../>
```

like

```
<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x217e7b8 name="z:row" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x217e754 name="ID_Poblacio" value="3">
```

and I cannot retrieve the rows using either:

```
s=cac.at_xpath("/*/z:row") or
s=cac.at_xpath("//z:row") or
s=cac.at_xpath("//row") or
s=cac.at_xpath("z:row")...
```

Probably I'm really fool but I cannot figure out which can be the issue.

Does anyone face this problem?

Thanks in advance.

P:S I tried to paste my cac file directly from bash but something wierd happens with format so I remove it from question. If anyone can explain how to do it I will appreciate it.

Comment: You probably need to register a namespace for the "z:" prefix.
You can try `s=cac.at_xpath("//xmlns:row")` (Nokogori should have registered it for you)
or `s=cac.at_xpath("//*:row")` (if you don't care about the namespace).
Or if you're "lazy", you can call `cac.remove_namespaces!` and then use `s=cac.at_xpath("//row")`.
But ideally, if you can, you should post your XML file, 
or extract of it with the headers and namespace declarations). 

See [this blog post](http://biztech.sheprador.com/?p=74) and [Nokogiri doc](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)

Comment: Give us the sample xml to help you out..

Comment: I had the same problem and went with `.remove_namespaces!` :) It didn't make a difference in my case

Answer (score 0):

Your XML element name contains a colon, but it is not in a [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) (otherwise the prefix and uri would show up in the dump of the node). Using element names with colons without using namespaces is valid, but can cause problems (like this case) so generally should be avoided. Your best solution, if possible, would be to either rename the elements in your xml to avoid the `:` character, or to properly use namespaces in your documents.

If you can’t do that, then you’ll need to be able to select such element names using XPath. A colon in the element name part of an XPath node test is always taken to indicate a namespace. This means you can’t directly specify a name with a colon that isn’t in a namespace. A way around this is to select all nodes and use an XPath function in a predicate to refine the selection to only those nodes you’re after. You can use a colon in an argument to `name()` and it won’t be interpreted as a namespace separator:

```
s=cac.at_xpath("//*[name()='z:row']")
```